# display matrix values and colormap

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib, imshow

I need to display values of my matrix using matshow.
However, with the code I have now I just get two matrices - one with values and other colored.
How do I impose them? Thanks :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

min_val, max_val = 0, 15

for i in xrange(15):
    for j in xrange(15):
        c = intersection_matrix[i][j]
        ax.text(i+0.5, j+0.5, str(c), va='center', ha='center')

plt.matshow(intersection_matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

ax.set_xlim(min_val, max_val)
ax.set_ylim(min_val, max_val)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(max_val))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(max_val))
ax.grid()
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to use `ax.matshow` not `plt.matshow` to make sure they both appear on the same axes.

If you do that, you also don't need to set the axes limits or ticks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

min_val, max_val = 0, 15

intersection_matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(max_val, max_val))

ax.matshow(intersection_matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

for i in xrange(15):
    for j in xrange(15):
        c = intersection_matrix[j,i]
        ax.text(i, j, str(c), va='center', ha='center')
```

Here I have created some random data as I don't have your matrix. Note that I had to change the ordering of the index for the text label to `[j,i]` rather than `[i][j]` to align the labels correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Could you please explain the step where you change the ordering of the index for the text label? Why is it necessary to change `i` and `j`?

Comment: Its to do with whether you are considering the array indexing as C ordering or FORTRAN ordering. You can read about it here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues

Answer (score 7):

In Jupyter notebooks this is also possible with DataFrames and Seaborn:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

min_val, max_val = 0, 15
intersection_matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(max_val, max_val))
cm = sns.light_palette("blue", as_cmap=True)
x=pd.DataFrame(intersection_matrix)
x=x.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
display(x)
```

[image]