# Plot matrix of weighted cells in grid with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, grid

I have a square matrix built from an array of random integers, defined below:

```
import numpy as np

dim_low, dim_high = 0, 20 #array of random integers' dimensions

matrix = np.random.random_integers(low = dim_low,high = dim_high, size=(dim_high,dim_high))
print(matrix) #the matrix of defined with repetitions of the array.
```

**Resulted matrix in the picture:** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEcCh.png

What could I do to plot the matrix generated in a grid with Matplotlib, in a way that the values of each cell (the weights) are printed in the center of each cell, and there's a scale from 0 to 20 in x an y axis, as in the **picture below** (notice that **'x'** and **'o'** are text in the example, what I need is the weights, in integer form, not text form):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mBuG.png  (**here**)

Comment: If you are capable of producing the image shown, what's the difference to putting your matrix elements in the text instead of some letters `"o"`? Which exact problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pulled most of this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887753/display-matrix-values-and-colormap).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

low_dim = 0
high_dim = 20

matrix = np.random.randint(low_dim, high_dim, (high_dim,high_dim))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(0, high_dim):
    for j in range(0, high_dim):
        val = matrix[i,j]
        ax.text(i+0.5, j+0.5, str(val), va='center', ha='center')

ax.set_xlim(low_dim, high_dim)
ax.set_ylim(low_dim, high_dim)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(high_dim))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(high_dim))
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

The right module for this would be seaborn. It has all the functionality you ask for and more...
Try using https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html. I won't take you through the different options because they're really well documented.
Goodluck!

BTW, you'll want to use a panda pivot table for comfortable compatibility.