# Custom colors in matplotlib when using matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an easy way to indicate a specific color for each element of a given matrix when using matplotlib. For example, assume we want to show 'x' as follow with three specific colors: red, black, and, white:

[image]

However, the only option I found out is using "cmap" which doesn't directly give you the option to "directly" specify the colors.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x= [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,1,2,1,1], [0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,1,1,1,1,1]]    
cax = ax.matshow(x,cmap=plt.cm.gray_r )
plt.show()
```

[image]

My question: how should I change my code to show the above red/black/white grid? [e.g 0 means black, 1 means white, and 2 means red] and in general how we can do it for a larger list of colors? like 10-15 colors.

In addition, how to assign to a certain element in the matix a certain color? for example in above, x[i][j] == 0 then color ='black' or x[i][j] == 2 then color ='red'

Thanks.

Comment: I recently found an easy solution to this problem. It involves creating a 3d numpy array that represents the desired colors of the data and plotting that rather than the original 2d data array. The solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66821752/7871710

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create your own color maps:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = ListedColormap(['k', 'w', 'r'])
cax = ax.matshow(x,cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

If you want to specify 10-15 colors you may run out of single-letter colors. In this case you can specify RGB triplets (e.g. `ListedColormap([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]])`) or various other [color formats](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html). Alternatively, use one of the pre-defined discrete ("qualitative") color maps listed [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

If the values in the matrix are not consecutive integers you can transform them before plotting.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,77,0,0,22,0], [0,1,1,2,1,1], [0,0,14,0,0,1], [0,1,1,1,1,1]])
u, i = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
y = i.reshape(x.shape)
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0],
#        [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks, @kazemakase.  Follow up question, how to assign to a certain element in the matix a certain color? for example in above, x[i][j] == 0 then color ='black' or x[i][j] == 2 then color ='red'

Comment: @superMind I don't fully understand the follow-up. The mapping 0->b, 1->w, 2->r is performed for every element i, j. Do you want special treatment for certain elements? In that case what about the other elements?

Comment: Let's say,x is sth like this: x= [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,77,0,0,22,0], [0,1,1,2,1,1], [0,0,14,0,0,1], [0,1,1,1,1,1]] and assume we have 6 colors (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6). The question is that how 0--> c1, 1-->c2, 2-->c3, 14-->c4, 22-->  c5, 77-->c6.

Comment: @superMind I think the easiest would be to transform x so that 14->3, 22->4, 77->5. Then the values map nicely to the colors again. I have updated the question to show how this can be done with numpy arrays and the help of `np.unique`.

Comment: Nice, this even works with just a single color and a masked array.

Comment: My solution, presented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66821752/7871710 , is independent of the ordering of the numbers in the original array. I was not able to use this solution for my particular use case.